# how to numerically integrate a variable that is being calculate in the program as a pointer (using e.g. trapezoidal rule) in c language

Tags: c, pointers, numerical-methods

I have a code, that was not made by me.
In this complex code, many rules are being applied to calculate a quantity, d(x). in the code is being used a pointer to calculate it.

I want to calculate an integral over this, like:
  W= Int_0 ^L d(x) dx  ?

I am doing this:

```
#define DX 0.003
void WORK(double *d, double *W)
{
    double INTE5=0.0;
    int N_X_POINTS=333;
    double h=((d[N_X_POINTS]-d[0])/N_X_POINTS); 
    W[0]=W[0]+((h/2)*(d[1]+2.0*d[0]+d[N_X_POINTS-1])); /*BC*/
    for (i=1;i<N_X_POINTS-1;i++) 
    {
        W[i]=W[i]+((h/2)*(d[0]+2*d[i]+d[N_X_POINTS]))*DX;
        INTE5+=W[i];
    }
    W[N_X_POINTS-1]=W[N_X_POINTS-1]+((h/2)*(d[0]+2.0*d[N_X_POINTS-1]+d[N_X_POINTS-2])); /*BC*/
}
```

And I am getting "Segmentation fault". I was wondering to know if, I am doing right in calculate W as a pointer, or should declare it as a simple double? I guess the Segmentation fault is coming for this.

Other point, am I using correctly the trapezoidal rule?

Any help/tip, will very much appreciate.

Luiz

Comment: this is not FORTRAN, you don't have to use all caps

Comment: In order to answer this we need to see the definitions and allocations of `d`, `W` and `Z`.

Comment: even in modern fortran you don't need all caps

Comment: @David Grayson And a little bit of http://ioccc.org

Comment: @Shin I know that, but take a look on netlib and you will see where I'm coming from.

Comment: @David Heffernan, thanks man, $d$ is a density of individuals, I am taking this from an specific problem of population dynamics. 
$W$ is being (should be) the integral over this density, i.e., the total number of it.
$Z$ was a mistake, I correct.

Comment: `int INTE5=0.0'`? Why assign a float to an int?

Comment: @ziulfer No. Show us how these 3 variables are both declared and allocated.  Please don't expect us to solve the problem without being able to see the code.  We can't see your screen.  The problem for sure is an array out of bounds error.  Hence the need to see how the arrays are allocated.

Comment: @all I am sorry guys. I know that everything is a complete mess. All this stuffs are somehow new to me. So, there is no 'Z', I've just removed it. It was supposed to be 'W' from the begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where that code come from, but it is a lot ugly and has some limits hard-encoded (333 points and increment by 0.003). To use it you need to "sample" properly your function and generate pairs (x, f(x))...

A possible clearer solution to your problem is [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#C).

Let us consider you function and let us suppose it works (I believe it does't, it's a really obscure code...; e.g. when you integrate a function, you expect a number as result; where's this number? Maybe INTE5? It is not given back... and if it is so, why the final update of the W array? It's useless, or maybe we have something meaningful into W?). How does would you use it?

The prototype

```
  void WORK(double *d, double *W);
```

means the WORK wants two pointers. What these pointers must be depends on the code; a look at it suggests that indeed you need two arrays, with N_X_POINTS elements each. The code reads from and writes into array W, and reads only from d. The N_X_POINTS int is 333, so you need to pass to the function arrays of at least 333 doubles:

```
   double d[333];
   double W[333];
```

Then you have to fill them properly. I thought you need to fill them with (x, f(x)), sampling the function with a proper step. But of course this makes no too much sense. Already said that the code is obscure (now I don't want to try to reverse engineering the intention of the coder...).

Anyway, if you call it with `WORK(d, W)`, you won't get seg fault, since the arrays are big enough. The result will be wrong, but this is harder to track (again, sorry, no "reverse engineering" for it).

Final note (from comments too): if you have `double a[N]`, then `a` has type `double *`.

Comment: How does this explain seg fault?

Comment: it doesn't. I supposed you wanted some working code for the algorithm, not just this one working. Likely, you've not passed the right amouint of data/room for d and W; you should have W and d as arrays of at least N_X_POINTS elements

Comment: i.e. `double d[N_X_POINTS], W[N_X_POINTS]; /* ... */ WORK(d, W); /* ... */` or somethin like this

Comment: +1 @ziulfer follow the link that Shin gives you. That links to code that is clear and intelligible. Your code, even when you get the seg fault fixed, is surely wrong.

Comment: In general the answer would be that "To use it you need to 'sample' properly your function and generate pairs (x, f(x))" means that the user has not sampled properly the function, so s/he gets seg fault. Hopefully comments that answer Heffrnan's question should make this clearer for the user.

Comment: ok, guys, thank you very much. I see that the problem should be in something else. That is ugly and not clear, and ....
But to integrate over a pointer, should I use another pointer?
Can you help me out with this?

Comment: the pointer just points to an sequence of double (i.e. array): with `double d[1000];`, if you pass to a function simply d, like in `WORK(d, W)`, d is nothing but a pointer to double(s). `*(d+1)` is d[1] and so on. In fact in your WORK code, even though you have a pointer passed as arg, it indexes it as an array; this is because A[B] is nothing but `*(A+B)`. Maybe was this your misunderstanding about the func?

Comment: @ShinTakezou Yes, I read better the link u sent me. so, just one more thing, finally i have to make declare in `WORK(*(d)(),w)`. And do the same for `d`, in all other parts of the code, where `d`is being calculated? Making return at the end of each? 
P.S.: I am sorry for all these stupid questions....

Comment: thank you, for sure it will help me a lot!!! I gonna try it, and asap I come back to you guys!!! this stackoverflow is really an amazing website

Comment: the code in the link uses a different approach: you pass the function you want to be integrated and the interval-range (basically). The WORK function wants two array (so I supposed you have to sample the function by yourself, but read the edited answer, where I doubt it is meaningful, it would need just one array, not two)

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault error often happens in C when you try to access some part of memory that you shouldn't be accessing.  I suspect that the expression `d[N_X_POINTS]`  is the culprit (because arrays in C are zero-indexed), but without seeing the definition of `d` I can't be sure.

Try putting informative `printf` debugging statements before/after each line of code in your function so you can narrow down the possible sources of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program that integrates $f(x) = x^2$ over the range [0..10].  It should send you in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double int_trapezium(double f[], double dX, int n)
{
   int i;
   double sum;

   sum = (f[0] + f[n-1])/2.0;
   for (i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
       sum += f[i];
   return dX*sum;
}

#define N 1000
int main()
{
    int i;
    double x;
    double from = 0.0;
    double to = 10.0;
    double dX = (to-from)/(N-1);
    double *f = malloc(N*sizeof(*f));

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        x = from + i*dX*(to-from);
        f[i] = x*x;
    }
    printf("%f\n", int_trapezium(f, dX, N));
    free(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, for sure it will help me a lot!!! I gonna try it, and asap I come back to you guys!!!this stackoverflow is really an amazing website